# asp.net is not compiling

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, razor

I'm a novice into programming. I did a lot of classic .asp in the old days, and now i want to look into razor.

I'm trying to run my first asp.net razor script on my desktop version of IIS.

It runs classic .asp fine, but the code:

The time is @DateTime.Now

does not compile, it just shows it as html in the aspx page.

I'm jusing DefaultPool in IIS and all .NET versions should be installed correctly.

Any one knows what I am missing?

Kind regards 
Klaus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThDHM.jpg)

Comment: The `@`-prefix suggests that you are trying to use Razor syntax, but the file extension to use for Razor is `.cshtml` (not `.aspx`).

Comment: There's a lot more to MVC than just razor templates. Since you've only worked with classic ASP previously, there will be quite a few new concepts to learn. It may be best to start with a working demo project, and experiment with modifying things until you're comfortable with how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The example you've given is razor syntax, but you're apparently trying to run it in a webform. This won't work.

Razor will need to be in a .vbhtml or .cshtml file.

If you want to use webform (aspx), that's fine also, but the correct syntax would be something like ...

```
<%= Now() %>
```

Comment: I was trying to use this from w3schools in some way: Razor Markup Razor is a simple markup syntax for embedding server code (C# or VB) into ASP.NET web pages. Example <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <title>Web Pages Demo</title> </head> <body> <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1> <p>The time is @DateTime.Now</p> </body> </html> The page above contains both ordinary HTML markup and Razor markup. But apparently I'm doing something wrong??

Comment: I want to use the first code sample on this page, but I have no idea how to get it running, i just get the code at text on the page: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/webpages_razor.asp

Comment: Their sample is a razor view template, .cshtml, or .vbhtml. The easiest way to learn to use it is to start with Visual Studio MVC project template. Creating an MVC application from scratch may be fairly difficult when you're just starting off.

Comment: @Klaus_Andersen Razor templates work in a fairly different way to classic ASP, in that you don't just have a standalone template that you request directly. Razor is just a part of the Model View Controller (MVC) framework. You would have a C# or VB.Net controller class, which handles a particular URL path or route. This controller creates an instance of an object or model, and then renders it using the razor view.
It's a bit of a steep learning curve coming from classic ASP, but well worth it. MVC is quite fun to work with once you've got the hang of it.